# Fastai export/load_learner: why it is another model after reloading it

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I have trained a resnet34 learner

```
tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=False)
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics=[accuracy])
learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot(suggestion=True)
learn.fit_one_cycle(10, min_grad_lr)
learn.recorder.min_grad_lr
learn.export(mypath+"Resnet34.pkl")
```

then I calculated accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score, I got: 0.77, 0.78, 0.77
after that I loaded the resnet model with:

```
learn = load_learner(path=mypath, file="Resnet34.pkl")
```

after that, I calculated accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score (as before, on exaclty the same validation set), and surprisingly I got lower values: 0.58, 0.61, 0.59.
I have torch 1.5.1+cpu, torchvision 0.6.1+cpu, fastai 1.0.61
Is there any bug/error somewhere?

Comment: Can you print out some hash (eg md5) of the exported model file to ensure it hasn't been changed? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-generate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: Can you print out some hash (eg md5) of the exported model file to ensure it hasn't been changed? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-generate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: Are the differences big? Remember that the weights are randomly assigned in the beginning. So, it may be the reason...